# Compress JSON responses in Phoenix framework

Tags: phoenix-framework

What is the best way to gzip JSON responses from my Phoenix API server?

Is there any GZIP plug or should I have `nginx` in front of Phoenix?

Comment: I am not sure if this is any help but I know Plug.Static has a GZIP option through Phoenix.Digest: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.Digest.html

If you search for gzip in your phoenix project you will see how it is used.

Comment: This is a better answer. The compress: true answer below doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure gzip compression for all responses from a particular endpoint, such as the one used by your API.

```
config :app_name, AppName.Endpoint,
  http: [compress: true]
```

Comment: Note that if you compress *https* responses, you may be open to http://breachattack.com